# Track pageviews in Google Analytics on partial url of Grails application

Tags: grails, google-analytics

For my Grails application I want to set up Google Analytics to track only "partial" url's. I 'll explain:

- a typical Grails url consists of the following parts: domain + application-name + controller + action + id
- e.g. www.mydomain.com/myapp/controller/action/12345

As far as I understand for Google Analytics the page to be tracked is identified by the entire url. For my purpose I'm not interested in the id part of the url: I want to know which actions have been performed, but I need not know for which id the action was executed.

And of course I would like a generic solution, because I have multiple controllers and multiple actions... Maybe some kind of filter stating "I want to track pages 3 levels deep (/myapp/controller/action)" would do? Or a filter stating "exclude everything from url after the last /"?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Pieter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is best answered by [this article](http://www.objectpartners.com/2011/06/07/google-analytics-page-tracking-in-grails-web-flow/).

As the other contributors suggested, I too thought the issue should be resolved in Google Analytics. I clicked around a bit and got hopelessly confused.

Solving the issue within Grails is much much easier. In short the answer is:

- in the Google Analytics tracking javascript there is a
  "_trackpageview" action
- this action can take as parameter the url you want to track
- in Grails I can simply add the stuff I want to track:
  application/controller/action
- my Google Analytics script is in my main template
- I just use: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','myapp/${controllerName}/${actionName}']);
- ("myapp" should be the name of your application)
- (${controllerName} and ${actionName} are generically available
  variables in the Grails views)

Hope this will help others.

Thnx for the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is best solved within the realm of Google Analytics, where you can create a specific report that ignores the id-part of the url.

That way you can just use Google Analytics at its easiest and need not make any code changes to your project

Comment: Totally agree. Perhaps I wasn't specific enough: my question is HOW to do this in Google Analytics :-) Reading up on the subject the way to go seems to be the use of filters: define Custom Filters where you can exclude parts of a Request URI. I'm looking for some help on exactly how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several approaches. First thing comes to my mind is taking one of these steps:

- Using profile filters ([more info](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/goals/index.html))
- Generating the same virtual pageviews on each action id ([more info](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/et_vps/index.html))
- Using advanced segments tool with a proper condition (page url pattern match) ([more info](http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/advanced_segmentation/index.html))

Each approach has its pros and cons, choosing proper one depends on the goal you are trying to achieve.